# Android 2.2 on Verizon, specifically Droid

Tags: motorola-droid, verizon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

Does anyone know when 2.2 will be released for Verizon phones?  Also, is there a way to install it currently?  I'd like to upgrade as soon as possible because it is really nice but, Verizon is so slow in getting these out.

Comment: official rollout should mostly be done by now (August 19)

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a release date yet. Every rumored date gets pushed back. The most recent was a July 13th date that is now pushed to 'August'. This is all hearsay, though.

Only way to currently get 2.2 is if you are rooted and install either a vanilla build of 2.2 or a custom ROM built with the 2.2 source code.

As soon as the official update hits, expect the 'update.zip' to be all over the web within the first day, then we can all download and install it (rooted or not).

- [How to root a Droid running 2.1](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/05/06/guide-to-rooting-android-2-1-on-a-motorola-droid/)
- Once rooted, download ROM Manager from the market. This app will download and install many different ROMs for you.

**NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE** :)

Answer (score 2):

Current speculation is the OTA update will be August 12.

You can also download the official Android 2.2 update file, no Root needed. ([Android Tapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/how-to-manually-install-android-2-2-on-verizon-motorola-droid/) has the details.)

Comment: A lucky (?) few got it last week, but they found a show-stopper and pulled the plug.  Eagerly waiting.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Update: Android 2.2 is now being sent to Verizon phones now as an automatic update.

Note: They still disable a few 2.2 features, like the mobile wi-fi hotspot option.

Comment: Note: this wasn't true at all... until 9/1...