# When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?

Tags: updates, 2.2-froyo, android-versions

Android 2.2 (FroYo, short for "Frozen Yogurt") was released over the Summer 2010, however not all of the devices that will get this update have received it yet. Each manufacturer and carrier needs to add their custom modifications before it can be officially released.

See also:

- [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2695/1465)

Comment: I think the dates are better in the answer. not the question. Firstly it would make more sense in Q&A format. Secondly you can accept it and remove this question from "unanswered" list

Comment: @LouisRhys: So, what are you thinking? One answer per model? Seems too granular. How about one answer per manufacturer?

Comment: maybe just one answer for evertything is a good idea too?

Comment: In [our discussion](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/174/placeholder-for-all-phone-os-upgrade-questions) we settled on having the information in the question. Feel free to continue this discussion there.

Comment: How should we handle phones which offered by two or more vendors and have different update schedules? The Samsung Intercept (which was just added to the list below) is offered by Sprint and Virgin Mobile (A Sprint subsidiary), and each vendor has different update schedules. Sprint updated their Samsung Intercepts a few days ago, Virgin Mobile customers are still waiting.

Comment: If we have that information, include it. See the *Samsung Galaxy S (International)* entry for example.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it's available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/why-arent-the-manufacturers-updating-the-phone-to-the-latest-android-version-wh)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This community wiki will list all of the known and rumored dates of upgrades for devices that shipped with a prior version of Android. If you have an update make sure to follow the format that's been established, and the following guidelines:

1. Keep phones in alphabetical order listing the manufacturer and model
2. Specify if the date is confirmed or rumored and link to the source
3. If there is an unofficial release, link to the site where it can be downloaded

If you don't have a high enough reputation score to edit the wiki (currently 100), leave your suggestion in a comment or answer and someone will update the list.

### Phones

**Acer Liquid E**

- Official: Nov. 19, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/11/19/acer-liquid-e-gets-android-2-2-upgrade/))

**HTC Aria**

- Official:

  - Southeast Asia: Dec. 17,2010 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2010/12/phones/htc-manufacturers-news/htc-starts-rolling-out-android-2-2-update-for-the-htc-aria/))

**HTC Desire**

- Official:

  - (Cellular South) Mar. 18, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/cellular-south-htc-desire-froyo-update-rolling-out))
  - (U.S. Cellular) Feb. 8, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/us-cellular-releases-froyo-htc-desire))
  - (Virgin Media) Nov. 11, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/froyo-available-desire-users-virgin-finally))
  - UK: (via HTC) Sep. 18, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/09/18/t-mobile-uks-htc-desire-froyo-update-now-officially-rolling-out/))
  - Canada: (Telus) Oct. 25, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.telusmobility.com/en/ON/htc_desire_support/trouble07.shtml))

**HTC G1**

- OTA: Never
- Unofficial: ([myTouch 3G port](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=811620))

**HTC Legend**

- Official: Europe Dec. 9, 2010 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/android-2-2-update-for-htc-legend-coming-december-9th-20101208/))

**HTC Magic**

- OTA: (Vodafone UK) 14 Dec 2010 ([confirmed](http://vodafoneuk.lithium.com/t5/Latest-Vodafone-News/Android-2-2-1-for-HTC-Magic/m-p/630265#M25))

**HTC myTouch 3G**

- Official: Jan. 12, 2011 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2011/01/09/all-mytouch-3g-owners-will-get-android-2-2-jan-12/))

**HTC myTouch Fender LE & myTouch 3G 3.5mm jack aka myTouch 3G 1.2**

- Official: Jan 25 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/mytouch-3g-12-and-fender-le-froyo-update-pushing-out-now))

**HTC myTouch 3G Slide**

- OTA: planned, no date ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2010/11/15/froyo-coming-to-the-mytouch-3g-slide/))

**HTC Wildfire**

- Official:

  - United Kingdom: Dec. 20, 2010 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/vodafone-htc-wildfire-froyo-update-released-today-20101220/))
  - Germany (T-Mobile): Dec. 21, 2010
  - rest of Europe: Week of Dec. 23, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2010/12/23/htc-wildfire-getting-froyo-this-week/))

**LG Ally**

- Official:

  - Jan. 19, 2011 ([source](http://phandroid.com/2011/01/19/psa-froyo-for-the-lg-ally-is-going-out-now/))

**LG Apex**

- Official: Q1, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/us-cellulars-froyo-updates-detailed-desire-mesmerize-early-february))

**Motorola CHARM**

- Official: **never** (will remain at Android 2.1) ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/02/09/motorola-says-its-older-low-range-android-devices-will-no-longer-get-upgrades/))

**Motorola CLIQ XT**

- Official: **never** (will remain at Android 1.5) ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/02/09/motorola-says-its-older-low-range-android-devices-will-no-longer-get-upgrades/))

**Motorola Defy**

- Europe, Asia, Middle East: 2Q 2011 ([source](http://androidcommunity.com/defy-to-get-android-2-2-quarter-2-2011-20101123/))

**Motorola FLIPOUT**

- Official: **never** (will remain at Android 2.1) ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/02/09/motorola-says-its-older-low-range-android-devices-will-no-longer-get-upgrades/))

**Motorola i1 (PTT)**

- Official: **never** (will remain at Android 1.5) ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/02/09/motorola-says-its-older-low-range-android-devices-will-no-longer-get-upgrades/))

**Motorola Milestone**

- Europe: Mar. 15, 2011 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2011/03/15/android-2-2-froyo-update-for-the-motorola-milestone-hits-europe/))
- Asia, Middle East: 4Q 2010 - initial rollout ([source](https://supportforums.motorola.com/community/manager/softwareupgrades))
- Asia-Pacific, Canada, Latin America: 1Q 2011 ([source](https://supportforums.motorola.com/community/manager/softwareupgrades))

**Motorola Milestone XT720**

- Official:

  - Cincinnati Bell: Jul. 4, 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/07/news/regional-carrier-declares-independence-from-slow-manufacturer-updates/))

**Samsung Acclaim**

- Official: Jan. 19, 2011, via download ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/01/19/samsung-acclaim-for-us-cellular-is-finally-moving-up-to-android-2-2-froyo/))

**Samsung Captivate**

- Official (via Kies):

  - (Canada - Rogers) Jan. 10, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-22-update-now-available-rogers-captivate-owners))
  - (U.S. - AT&T) Feb. 24, 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/02/phones/samsung/official-froyo-update-for-the-att-samsung-captivate-will-be-released-tomorrow/))

**Samsung Continuum**

- Official: Jan. 18, 2011 ([rumored](http://www.androidcentral.com/froyo-samsung-fascinate-coming-jan-10))

**Samsung Epic 4G**

- Official: Feb. 22, 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidandme.com/2011/02/carriers/sprint/sprints-samsung-epic-4g-froyo-update-only-hours-away/))
- Unofficial: Nov. 7, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/sprint-epic-4g-froyo-leak-made-available-all))

**Samsung Fascinate**

- Official:

  - Canada: early 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2010/11/18/canadian-galaxy-s-handsets-get-android-2-2-news/))
  - United States: Apr. 21, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2011/04/20/verizon-wireless-announces-froyo-update-samsung-fascinate-starts-april-21/))

**Samsung Galaxy 3 (I5800 / I5801)**

- Official some time in November/December 2010 ([source](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-apollo-3/160300-root-froyo-samsung-i5800-galaxy-3-a.html#post1808621))
- Unofficial: Dec. 12, 2010 ([instructions](http://ok-interesting.blogspot.com/2010/12/samsung-galaxy-3-froyo.html))
- India: [14th April 2011](http://androidos.in/2011/04/samsung-galaxy-3-i5801-gets-android-2-2-froyo-update-in-india/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20AndroidosinIndia%20%28Androidos.in%20%C2%BB%20India%29)

**Samsung Galaxy 5 (I5500)**

- Official some time in November/December 2010 ([source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9431054&postcount=224))

  - Belgium/Luxembourg: Apr. 2011 ([hearsay](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo/5137#5137))
- Unofficial: Dec. 4, 2010 ([instructions and download](http://www.phonereleaseinfo.com/212/flash-guide-froyo-galaxy-5/))

**Samsung Galaxy A (Korea)**

- OTA: Nov. 15, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/11/15/samsung-galaxy-a-and-s-in-korea-get-froyo-as-does-vodafones-galaxy-s/))

**Samsung Galaxy S (International)**

- Official:

  - T-Mobile: 2nd week of Dec. 2010 (tentative) ([source](http://androidcommunity.com/galaxy-s-android-2-2-delay-addressed-by-t-mobile-maybe-due-next-week-20101202/))
  - Europe: (O2) Nov. 15, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/o2s-version-samsung-galaxy-s-getting-froyo-nov-15)), (Vodafone) Nov. 15, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/11/15/samsung-galaxy-a-and-s-in-korea-get-froyo-as-does-vodafones-galaxy-s/))
  - Korea: Nov. 15, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/11/15/samsung-galaxy-a-and-s-in-korea-get-froyo-as-does-vodafones-galaxy-s/))
  - Middle East: Nov. 15, 2010
  - UK: (via Samsung Kies) Nov. 4, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/11/05/confirmed-froyo-hitting-galaxy-today/))

**Samsung Intercept**

- Official:

  - Sprint: Dec. 17, 2010 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2010/12/17/samsung-intercept-gets-android-2-2-froyo/))
  - Virgin Mobile: Mar. 25, 2011 ([confirmed](http://www.androidarena.com/2011/02/23/virgin-mobiles-samsung-intercept-will-get-its-dose-of-froyo-around-march-25th/))

**Samsung Mesmerize**

- Official: Mar. 24, 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2011/03/24/samsung-mesmerize-froyo-update-now-available/))

**Samsung Moment**

- Official: **never** ([confirmed by Sprint](http://www.androidcentral.com/sprint-hero-moment-wont-get-froyo))
- Unofficial:

**Samsung Vibrant**

- Official:

  - (Canada) Dec.9, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/12/09/bells-samsung-galaxy-s-vibrant-gets-froyo/)) ([rollout suspended 20 Dec 2010](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/12/20/samsung-vibrant-froyo-retracted/))
  - (U.S. T-Mobile) Jan. 21, 2011 ([confirmed](http://forums.t-mobile.com/t5/Samsung-Vibrant/Samsung-Vibrant-software-upgrade-to-Android-2-2-Froyo-now/td-p/678871))
- Unofficial: Nov. 9, 2010 ([confirmed](http://androidspin.com/2010/11/09/guide-how-to-install-the-unofficial-2-2-froyo-build-on-your-t-mobile-vibrant/))

**Sony Ericsson Xperia X10**

- Official: **never** ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/no-android-updates-for-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-beyond-2-1-20110106/))

### Tablets

**Archos 28/32/43/70/101**

- Official: Nov. 30, 2010 ([confirmed](http://www.androidcentral.com/archos-internet-tablets-receive-froyo-today))

**Dell Streak**

- Official:

  - unbranded/unlocked: Nov. 15, 2010  ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/11/15/dell-streak-froyo-upgrade-going-out-today-for-unlocked-devices-late-december-for-carrier-specific-devices/))
  - AT&T: Jan. 12, 2011 ([confirmed](http://androidcommunity.com/att-dell-streak-froyo-update-not-due-until-january-12-20101209/))
  - O2: Dec. 15, 2010 ([confirmed](http://phandroid.com/2010/12/14/o2-uks-dell-streak-getting-froyo-this-week/))

**ViewSonic ViewPad 10**

- Unofficial: Nov. 12, 2010 ([source](http://androidcommunity.com/viewsonic-viewpad-10-android-2-2-update-coming-20101112/))

### Other devices

**Barnes & Noble Nook Color**

- Official: Apr. 20, 2011 ([confirmed](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2011/04/nook-color-gets-froyo-flash-facebook-and-angry-birds.ars))
- Unofficial: Dec. 6, 2010 ([video](http://androidcommunity.com/nookcolor-android-2-2-froyo-hack-revealed-video-20101206/))

---

This is not specific to Froyo, but this forum posts lists the rough dates for all Android versions for all Motorola models https://supportforums.motorola.com/community/manager/softwareupgrades