# Android 2.2 update for samsung Galaxy 3 (I5801 and I5800)

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, samsung-galaxy-apollo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

when android 2.2 update will available for Samsung Galaxy 3(i.e Samsung I5801 and I5800)... ? do you have any idea when it is going to available... Is there any otherway around for installing non official 2.2 on it...?

Thanks

Please note that samsung galaxy 3 !=(is not equal to) Samsung Galaxy S... so please don't post answer that update is available for Galaxy S.. that update can not be installed in Galaxy 3

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Answer (score 5):

The original target was September 23rd of this year, but as of October 28, 2010, Samsung advised that there are some errors they're still working on for the Froyo release for this phone:
http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-apollo-3/160300-root-froyo-samsung-i5800-galaxy-3-a.html#post1808621

There is no updated target date at this time.