# Does SAMSUNG I5500 GALAXY 5 can be upgraded into Android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

I'm planning to buy an android phone and I've heard that SAMSUNG I5500 GALAXY 5 is the cheapest one. My question is, does SAMSUNG I5500 GALAXY 5 can be upgraded into Android 2.2?

Comment: Upgrading it involves connecting your phone to your PC via Kies, if you have problems with doing that you can see the solutions in this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/fails-to-install-mtp-usb-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Samsung have already released an official Android 2.2 update for the i5500 in the UK. So there is an official version, and it should be going to other countries and service providers, but unfortunately you may have to wait for it.

Source http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9431054&postcount=224 and http://www.samsungfirmwareworld.com/froyo-t1602.html

Also be aware that there is a specific post here for tracking when various phones are getting Froyo here: [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo) I've updated it with info on the i5500 and thta's a good place to keep an eye on for further info.