# What can you do with Samsung Kies for Android phones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies

I only recently managed to [connect my Galaxy S with Kies via USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/fails-to-install-mtp-usb-device). And I've upgraded it to Froyo 2.2. What can you do in Samsung Kies other than upgrading your firmware. I've seen the interface and there doesn't seem to be a lot of interesting that you can do with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, you can upgrade the device software.  You can also back your contacts, text messages up, and you can sync photos or videos/movies both ways.

You can view movies from your phone on your pc directly, that goes both ways; watch from cell on pc and from pc on cell. I believe you also can download apps from kites onto your cell but that doesn't work anymore because of google's market policies.  Apparently, you also can make your cell work as a modem, but I didn't try that so...

Anyways, as edelcom and mru said before me it still needs some work to live up to what it should do and to keep up with handset itself.

Lastly, in samsung defense, kies isn't just for androids, it's their software for the whole cellphones lines, and many users are happy with it, obviously not us, android handsets' owners.

Comment: But the thing is, other than checking for and loading firmware through Kies it's actually far easier to do all that without Kies. All my contacts and calendar are constantly syncing and backing up to Google Mail, I can already just drag and drop movies between phone and pc, and the Samsung Apps link on the phone works, whereas the one in Kies is for their legacy non-Android phones. When you have the Froyo update you can use Android's built-in tethering to use your phone as a modem, none of this needs Kies. Once Samsung start using OTA updates I'll uninstall Kies as it will have no further use.

Comment: Yes, I agree to all of that, and I, also, don't use it at all, I just tried those things out for the sake of answering the question.
The question is; do you really think that Samsung will do OTA updates?! I hope so.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct . At least I don't use KIES for anything apart from upgrading the firmware.

Lately it's better, but I think that the KIES software is far from the quality of the Galaxy phone and it's operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are right. You may use it for synchronizing your data between the mobile and the computer, but nobody really wants to do so with such crappy kind of software.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install kies because i needed the samsung-win7-usb-dirvers, that are neccessary to connect laptop to internet via cellphone via usb. found no other source where i can get the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This software may be used for:

- Data backup
- Data transfer (between a Windows or Mac PC, and a Samsung    mobile
  device), limited to certain media file formats
- Multimedia    (audio,    photos, video, etc.) management, but limited
  to certain file       formats; for example, Kies does not recognise
  .avi files
- Purchase/acquisition of additional or special device    features
- Device     firmware and operating system (OS version)    upgrades

**Source:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies