# Is there any Android 2.2 updrate available for Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

if yes, how to upgrade it with out going service center.

Comment: duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What model do you have?  There are a billion (hyperbole) Galaxy S models.  There is a 2.2 update for the US Captivate, for the international i9000, and for others.

You can get the update OTA (over the air) if you have stock (unaltered) 2.1, a notification will show on your phone (on *most* carriers).  You can also download it through Samsung Kies (see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/fails-to-install-mtp-usb-device)).  Finally, you can find an upload of it and flash it to your phone through a Windows tool called Odin.

You can also use ROM Manager to flash a custom ROM, which will get you 2.2 early if it hasn't been officially released yet.  Search XDA if you want one of those ROMs.

Comment: I have SAmsung Galaxy GT-19000

Answer (score 0):

I have upgrade my Samsung Galaxy S from 2.1 to 2.2 without problems a few weeks ago.

If you connect your phone to the pc and start KIES, it should inform you if an upgrade is available.

Comment: Yesterday i was trying to update my galaxy s GT i9000, when i connect it to kies it shows message for to upgrade and the i clicked on firmware upgrade, it started with an progress bar and when it went to 100% it tried to reconnect mobile and the again it show "firmware available want to upgrade" and this time when i click on upgrade it does not any progress bar but tried to reconnect and then same message displayed. So basically i am not able to upgrade it.

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt: Make sure you have the very latest of KIES installed. A previous version of KIES did not work on my pc either.

Comment: yes i have latest.