# Why won't Kies let me tried to update to Froyo again after a failed upgrade attempt?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, updates, 2.1-eclair, samsung-kies

Yesterday I connected my i9000 to Kies which showed a message about the Froyo upgrade. I clicked on Firmware Upgrade, it started with an progress bar, and when it got to 100% it tried to reconnect to the phone and it again showed "Firmware available. Want to upgrade?" I clicked on upgrade again but it did not show any progress bar, just but tried to reconnect and then displayed the update message again.

Now whenever I connect the phone to Kies the "Firmware Update" link is disabled.  I thought that the phone might have been successfully updated despite everything in About it still shows `2.1 update 1`.

How can I fix this and update my Galaxy S to 2.2?

Comment: I'm assuming reconnect = reboot. Did the phone show a warning triangle with the Android robot shoveling and the text "Downloading..." after any reboot?

Comment: That model seems to be particularly problematic. Notice: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/why-is-my-samsung-kies-not-detecting-my-galaxy-s-gt-i9000 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/is-there-any-specific-reason-why-kies-does-not-detect-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/cannot-update-samsung-i9000

Comment: Its better to choose an official firmware (of your country) and flash it manually. Go to AndroidAdvices.com and search for your device. The site provides well tested step-by-step guide. It provides firmware too.

Comment: Use your country firmware for device and your warranty will be intact.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the official drivers installed from Samsung.com, then reboot your device and PC and try again.  You can also try putting it into [download mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Download_Mode) before using Kies:

1. Remove the battery
2. Hold VolumeDown plus the Home key plus Power.  While holding,

   1. Reinsert the battery.
   2. Release the power button, still holding the others, about 1 second after the white "GT-I9000" text appears.
   3. After a few seconds a yellow triangle with an android in it should appear, this is Download Mode.  If it doesn't, try this again while holding Power the whole time.

Comment: why we need to do 1. point? and if we start download mode without kies then will it connect to internet ?

Comment: You can't get into download mode by just doing steps 2 and 3, you have to do 1 as well.  Download mode just boots your phone into a mode where it will accept firmware upgrades -- Kies normally puts your phone into that mode automatically, but sometimes it fails.  So doing it manually may help.  Download mode does not connect to the internet or the cell network.

Comment: @Jeevan The easiest way to install the correct version of the drivers is to use the "Update Drivers" command within Kies when you click on the Kies logo, don't use the ones from the website, as they may not be right for your version of Kies.