# problem while connecting samsung galaxy gt-i5801 to pc via samsung kies

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Samsung Kies not detecting my Galaxy S GT I9000?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/why-samsung-kies-not-detecting-my-galaxy-s-gt-i9000)

i have tried everything for the connection of my galaxy to pc but all in vain... i am unable to understand *#7284# code... as it has uart and usb both... please suggest something how can i connect my cell phone to pc via samsung kies

Answer (score 0):

This might help :
[possible duplicate question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/why-samsung-kies-not-detecting-my-galaxy-s-gt-i9000)