# Samsung Galaxy Y won't connect to the computer

Tags: usb

I'm having problem connecting my Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 to the computer using via USB.

Whenever I connect it, it automatically charges. Before there was a prompt to connect it to the computer but now it just charges directly. I have tried downloading the Samsung Kies but it still won't connect.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4319/how-can-i-get-kies-to-detect-my-galaxy-s-gt-i9000-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

2 places to check:

1. Settings -> Wireless and Network -> USB Settings, and select "Ask on connection".
2. Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging [disable USB debugging]

Comment: Which version(s) of Android do these work for?

Comment: I can confirm it works Upto Gingerbread.

Comment: **Thanks.** I get prompted (*for MTP or PTP*) when I plug in an **SGS3 Mini** (with 4.1.1). *It connects (but does not work) under Nautilus/Ubuntu **12.10**.* But for my Samsung **Tab2 7.0** tablet (with 4.0.3) I have no USB settings (except enable/disable debugging). *My PC does not even detect the device attached.*

Comment: Oh!
This post has some solutions : http://askubuntu.com/questions/43086/how-to-transfer-files-from-to-an-android-device

Comment: I've tried most of these. They don't seem very stable ,and do **not** generally work for Samsung devices.

Comment: I have here a Galaxy Y with the default Samsung-provided GB image, and the first setting you list does not exist.

Comment: i still don't find the said options.Under the Wirless and network settings there is only usb utilities option and if i click on that there's USB mass storage with tap the button below to copy files between computer and sd card.With a connect storage to pc button.When i click on that there's a Attention pop-up with USB is connected.Remove the cable.How do i get the said option>

Answer (score 1):

When I experience this, turning the phone off and on again with the USB connected seems to make it work.

I recommend you turn it on and off again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a broken cable and/or connector:

Install [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) and unplug the USB cable then clear the logs, then re-plug the USB cable. You should see something like this:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
D/Vold    (  132): USB connected
D/Vold    (  132): Share method ums now available
I/StorageNotification(  263): UMS connection changed to true (media state mounted)
D/Vold    (  132): USB connected
D/Tethering(  185): sendTetherStateChangedBroadcast 1, 0, 0
D/Tethering(  185): interfaceAdded :usb0
D/BluetoothNetworkService(  185): updating tether state
D/BluetoothNetworkService(  185): interface usb0
W/Tethering(  185): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
D/dalvikvm(  580): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 53% free 2705K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 57ms
D/dalvikvm(  639): GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 51% free 2814K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 61ms
```

If it's just something like this, your connection is not detected (broken cable,...):

```
D/SettingsAppWidgetProvider(  639): Widget is from a previous version... Let's update
D/SettingsAppWidgetProvider(  639): No instances yet... Wait for at least one instance to exist before adding global settings
D/dalvikvm(  263): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 49% free 3079K/6023K, external 911K/990K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(  639): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 51% free 2814K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 60ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slide downwards and tap "USB Connected".
From there, you'll see the "Connect USB storage" button. 
Just tap it, and wait for the android image to change from green to orange.
Now, you're connected.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing and reinserting your SD card.