# Do I need Android SDK to connect my phone in USB debug mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, adb, windows, usb-debugging

I'm following the steps provided [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=739304) to root my Samsung Captivate (Galaxy-S).  I install the USB drivers in the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=728929) provided.  Whenever I connect my phone, I get the error `There was a problem installing this hardware... SAMSUNG Android Composite ADB Interface`.  I do have USB Debug mode checked on my phone.

The googling I have done on this issue mention downloading the Android SDK, but I have heard no mention of needing this on the XDA developers forum or in any other conversation about rooting.  So, I wanted to ensure that downloading the Android SDK was necessary, or would even fix my problem before I bother installing it and its dependencies (Java JDK).  I'm running Windows XP.

Note:  Although I'm running a 64-bit machine, I Installed the x86 Samsung Drivers since Windows XP is a 32-bit OS.  I hope that's right.

[image: Samsung Driver error]

Comment: Slightly confused by your talk of 64-bit and XP. What OS are you running on your PC and is it a 32-bit or 64-bit OS. Normally you install the same "bit-ness" drivers as your OS is, so if you're running a 64-bit OS on your PC, install the 64-bit drivers. But your screenshot looks like it's XP, and it's a long time since I heard of anyone using the half-baked 64-bit version of XP.

Comment: @GAThrawn, I'm running Windows XP 32-bit (not sure if there is a 64-bit version).

Comment: ah right, so you were saying that the pc hardware itself is 64-bit. Yes in that case the 32-bit drivers are the right ones to install. There is a 64-bit version of XP, but you really don't want to use it, it is very bad.

Comment: You will need the drivers on Windows all right. But for "simple ADB communication", you won't need the full SDK installation. See [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to install the Android SDK.  The SDK's drivers don't work for the Galaxy S, actually, at least not the last time I tried.

You best bet is to download Samsung Kies and update the drivers through it, as per [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/fails-to-install-mtp-usb-device/3365#3365) to another question.  You can get Kies most easily from Samsung UK [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/android/GT-I9000HKDXEU/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=support).

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is downloading the UK version of Kies a problem if I'm in the U.S.? Is there any difference between the U.S. and UK versions?

Comment: @Chance Actually, the only difference I know of is that you can tether your computer to your phone over USB if you use the full version of UK Kies, whereas the US version doesn't allow it.  If you have one of the US variants though (Fascinate, Vibrant, Captivate, or Epic 4G) you should get Kies from the US site for that phone specifically -- just in case the drivers are different from the GT-i9000 drivers.

Comment: You can also install pdanet on your machine, it has a lot of Android phone drivers bundled together in the installer.  You can uninstall the application after it installs the drivers. http://www.junefabrics.com/android/

Comment: Okay, here was the problem.  I had multiple drivers, and Windows was automatically installing one that did not work.  So, I went to `Device Manager`, right-clicked, selected `Properties...`, selected the `Driver` tab, selected `Update Driver...`.  Then I chose to `Install from a list or specific location` then selected `Don't search. I will choose the driver to install.`  I selected `Android ADB Interface` but I don't know where it came from (Kies, PDANet, or USBDeview).  In list mode it's not clear where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, all that's needed are the bits to make ADB (Android Debug Bridge) operate, which on Windows are the two libraries (AdbWinApi.dll and AdbWinUsbApi.dll).  But, that really shouldn't be necessary for a commercial product.