# Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT i5801) - Waiting for FROYO Update

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-apollo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

I have purchased **"Samsung Galaxy 3" Model number is GT-5801** - an android enabled phone, currently it is having Android 2.1 firmware, **`i would like to know whether it is upgradable to the upcoming version or not?`** I am not finding  "System Updates" options anywhere in the phone so please let me know.

I dont want to have updated firmware with the JailBreak or such kind of way !!

Comment: Please see the When will my phone get Android 2.2 post http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Comment: and also it maybe a good idea to change the question title