# will samsung galaxy 5 get android 2.2 update

Tags: samsung-galaxy-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

will samsung galaxy 5 get android 2.2 update ??

Comment: should a mod remove the email address?

Comment: duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo

Answer (score 0):

You can [upgrade to Froyo for the Galaxy 5](http://cellphoneforums.net/samsung/t319497-flash-guide-froyo-galaxy-5-a.html) already - it was just released by a few guys recently. See this post on Samfirmware - samfirmware.com/WEBPROTECT-i5500.htm, for more information. Otherwise by mid-December almost all regions should have it appearing on your official Samsung Kies tool.

PS. I don't have a Galaxy 5 but a college does.

Comment: perhaps you should clarify if it is an unofficial way to update and requires rooting?

Answer (score 0):

The official date is [some time in November/December 2010](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9431054&postcount=224), should depend on your location.

See also [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo) for a centralised location of all phone froyo update schedule.