# Upgrade Samsung Galaxy 5 I5503 into Android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I have a Samsung Galaxy 5 I5503 running Android 2.1. Does Android 2.2 is available for my device? If yes, How can I update the firmware and what should I do first before upgrading it? Thanks.