# How to update HTC Wildfire to froyo (android 2.2)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-wildfire

This is not [duplicate of "When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo) as I read there that official UK update was on 20 December 2010. I have phone in 3 and I cannot find any way to update.

If I enter into settings and try to do scheduled check it informs that phone is up to date. Firmware version is "2.1.-update1".

How to update to froyo

Comment: You do realize that we're not omniscient and only posting what other news sites are reporting? They could be wrong.

Comment: @Al Everett: I do realize. I cannot find any reference in my post that you have deceive me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the same way as any other update.

`Menu | Settings | About phone | System updates`

If it tells you that "Your system is currently up to date" then your carrier hasn't released the update for your phone yet. (They usually do staggered rollouts so as not to overload anything.)

Comment: Probably it was delayed :(

Comment: There are sometimes options for getting the update manually, but I don't that I've seen anything for the Wildfire.