# Does the HTC Droid Incredible Ship with Android 2.2 (Froyo)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-droid-incredible

I am just now ordering the HTC Droid Incredible. Will it come with the 2.2 version of the OS already installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [tech specs](http://www.htc.com/us/products/droid-incredible-verizon#tech-specs) on HTC's site states that its platform is Android 2.2 (Froyo).

Comment: That doesn't mean it will ship with 2.2, especially if it's coming from a carrier.

Comment: @Matthew Read. Good point, depending on the carrier, I suppose you can interpret it as it _supports_ 2.2 but may not ship with it. If it is an HTC Droid Incredible from Verizon, I can vouch that it now runs 2.2 (whether it ships "with" it or updates once you turn it on is another question).

Comment: 2.2 has been out long enough, and the device is popular enough, that any new Incredible that the OP orders is going to ship with 2.2.  In fact, I think that *all* SLCD Incredibles (which the OP will get) are 2.2.