# What country is my Motorola MILESTONE from? Can I install a Froyo update from Motorola Droid on it?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, motorola-milestone

I bought it at Amazon.com, and had it delivered to a friend's house in Massachusetts. I flew to the US, visit my friend, did some tourism, and brought the phone back with me to Brazil, where I put in my GSM chip and it works just fine. Here is the phone info:

- Model number: Milestone
- Firmware version: 2.1-update1
- Firmware configuration version: GAS_EMEA_USASHLS00RTINT_P012

The box says: SM,A853,TR,RETAIL,LICBRZ

So, I should be waiting for an update for what? Europe, like it says in [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)? Or Latin America? Or can I get 2.2 safely from somewhere else? The software looks pretty American to me. What if I follow the instructions from [this site](http://digitalconqurer.com/gadgets/motorola/install-android-2-2-froyo-update-for-motorola-droid-milestone-without-rootinghow-to/)? Do I risk bricking my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Motorola update software will recognize the correct origin, so you could always try to get the official Froyo upgrade.

Click around on this page to get instructions: http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Support/GB-EN/froyo/milestonenotification.htm

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Motorola Droid and Motorola Milestone are two different phones, although they look the same. The XT720 (aka Motoroi or Sholes Tablet) is another phone from the Milestone family, but without a keyboard.

The Software is NOT compatible, flashing a SBF file for the wrong phone will result in a bricked device. If you flash a custom ROM via an update.zip or nandroid image, you won't get past the Motorola-Logo on boot, but it's still possible to flash the right ROM.

> - Model number: Milestone Firmware
> - version: 2.1-update1 Firmware
> - configuration version: GAS_EMEA_USASHLS00RTINT_P012
>
> The box says: SM,A853,TR,RETAIL,LICBRZ

This is indicating you got the standard Milestone, the A853, with the South-East Asia firmware (RTINT). You can flash every Milestone (A853) RO, but it's possible, that 3G won't work due to different frequencies.

I think, a Brazil ROM (Vivo?!) was leaked some time ago, but there's no official release yet.

Custom ROMs:
Edgard Castro maintains a Brazilian AOSP ROM (http://code.google.com/p/shadowmodbr/) and there is an unofficial version of the CyanogenMod 7 (2.3.3, Gingerbread). More info here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=670