# Where and how can I upgrade my Galaxy 5 legally to Froyo?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-5, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I have a Galaxy 550 and want to upgrade it to android 2.2 where and how can i do this legal?

thanks already.

Answer (score 1):

If the update is available in your region, take it to your nearest Samsung authorised service centre and get it flashed. Make sure to back up all your data and perform a factory reset before handing it across.

I'm uncertain about what you intend to mean by "legal"?

Comment: Isn't it possible to upgrade to android 2.2 using Samsung's Kies (of course, supposing that the update would already be available)?

Comment: @Rabarberski - Indeed it is. Provided, as you mention, the update is available for the particular region.

Comment: Is there some easy way to know when Samsung will make it available for my region? I've looked for RSS on their site but couldn't find any.

Comment: Not really - although I'd recommend you check out http://samfirmware.com - it's an unofficial repository of official Samsung Firmwares (not customized).

Answer (score 1):

It depends also on your wireless provider. 
Even if Samsung releases an update, that provider may need to adjust it to fit their technical (and commercial) needs.