# is there any official froyo upgrade from samsung for galaxy 5 in India?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, samsung-galaxy-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

Hi,

I am a galaxy 5 user from India, there were news about froyo update for galaxy 5 but my kies [downloaded from samsung site] doesn't show any upgrades. I don't want to root my device if there is any upgrade available for galaxy 5, or will be available in near future.

Can you tell me if this upgrade available here?

Comment: This question on Froyo availability for phones has everything we know about Froyo releases http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/ Froyo does seem to have been released for your model in some regions, but unfortunately no one's provided any info about your region. There are two likely reasons for the delay, either the Froyo release hasn't yet been customized for your region and language, or it is available but your phone company hasn't certified the release yet and are currently blocking it. I would suggest checking with your phone company, if you can find more please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Asia Froyo firmware released by Samsung. It's available on the http://www.samfirmware.com repository. You'll need to register and login.

You can then flash this official un-modified firmware by using the ODIN software.

I5508ZCKP2 is the Jan 2011 released Froyo firmware update for the Galaxy I5500 or Galaxy 5 as it's known otherwise.