# Can I run Android 2.2 on an Android 2.1 ZTE Racer?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, custom-roms, zte-racer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I'm going to buy a ZTE Racer which comes with Android 2.1.  What can I do to upgrade it to 2.2?  ZTE didn't release an official upgrade.  Would CyanogenMod be an option?

Answer (score 1):

[The CyanogenMOD wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) lists supported phones; the Racer isn't included.  Looks like there are [some custom ROMs on MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/category/511/zte-racer-roms-rom-customisation/), though.