# Gingerbread upgrade for Samsung Galaxy Gio?

Tags: updates, samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-gio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.3 update (Gingerbread)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-3-update-gingerbread)

A few days ago I bought the [Samsung Galaxy Gio](http://www.samsung.com/galaxyace/gio_overview.html), an Android phone that ships with Froyo. My regional Samsung site [implies](http://www.samsung.com/be/consumer/mobile-phone/mobile-phone/mobile-phones/GT-S5660DSALUX/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=support) that a Gingerbread upgrade is available to me.

I then installed Samsung Kies to see if I could upgrade the firmware, but it said that currently no update was available for my device. ([Related discussion about the cryptic update message.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11872/samsung-kies-this-version-of-the-device-can-not-be-updated-never))

[image: Samsung Kies]

How do I find out whether Samsung plans to release an official Gingerbread upgrade for my device?

Are there any unofficial firmware upgrades available that work with my device? Would you recommend them? What about security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I can find suggests that a Gingerbread update is assumed because firmware has been leaked.  So you can't (yet) get it through something official like Kies.  [This guide](http://androidadvices.com/how-to-update-samsung-galaxy-gio-s-5560-to-gingerbread-xxkpa-2-3-3-firmware/) shows how to install the leaked version if you're so inclined.

Comment: So an official update appears to be on its way? In that case I'll wait for Samsung to release the upgrade.