# Upgrading from Android 1.6 to 2.2

Tags: updates, 2.2-froyo, 1.6-donut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I'm having issues to upgrade my tablet to the 2.2 system. It's a generic tablet, from Kaser, I'm using it to develop a specific application. Now the specs changed, and I need it to run on 2.2. I had a look at their website and there is no info about the upgrading. Is it possible?

[Thier page](http://www.kasercorp.com/productcart/pc/kaser-downloads.htm)

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a pretty obscure device. You might have better luck just contacting the manufacturer.

Comment: Yeh I did this and I was able to get the instructions and the drivers to upgrade my android. Thank you very much =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have complete kernel sources for your device from the manufacturer, then compile your own kernel and AOSP and flash the device.. I guess this is the only approach if you don't have any alternate solutions

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I managed to get the instructions and the drivers to upgrade my android.